# Rails can't get select to populate partial form on change

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails generated select that holds the customer's shipping addresses. On selecting one of their addresses, I'm trying to display editable text fields where they can update the different parts of their address.

The back-end process seems to be working but I can't get anything to generate.

```
Started GET "/get_sh_address?sh_addr_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-19 15:13:25 -0400                                                 
Processing by CustomersController#get_sh_address as */*                                                                               
  Parameters: {"sh_addr_id"=>"1"}                                                                                                     
  ShippingAddress Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "shipping_addresses".* FROM "shipping_addresses" WHERE "shipping_addresses"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [
["id", "1"]]                                                                                                                          
  Rendered customers/get_sh_address.html.erb (0.0ms)                                                                                  
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

customers_controller.rb

```
     def get_sh_address
    @sh_address = ShippingAddress.find(params[:sh_addr_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end    
  end
```

I have a customer_edits.js file where I put this:

```
  $("#sh_addresses_0").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).children(":selected").val();
    var params = 'sh_addr_id=' + id;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/get_sh_address",
      data: params
    })
});
```

My show.html.erb where I have the select and empty div

```
<%= collection_select(:sh_addresses, 0, @shipping_addresses, :id, :sh_full_address, {include_blank: 'Select a Shipping Address to Edit'}) %>
<div id="e_shipping_addresses">

</div>
```

I made a _get_sh_address.js.erb that contains:

```
$('#e_shipping_addresses').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'sh_address')).html_safe %>");
```

And the partial it is supposed to render:

```
<%= @sh_address.sh_address1 %>
```

My routes:

```
  get "/get_sh_address" => "customers#get_sh_address", as: :shipping_address
```

I know i'm not rendering a text field yet but I'm just trying to get it working with the above. It passes the param and finds the record but I can't get it to show the values

Comment: try adding `accepts: "text/javascript"` to your jquery ajax request

Comment: also rename  `_get_sh_address.js.erb` to `get_sh_address.js.erb` as it's not a partial

Comment: That was the issue lol. Took off the _ and it works now.. thanks :D